# Resizing my mat image in opencv

Tags: c++, opencv

I need help in resizing my image in opencv. Somehow the code I used before that  worked totally fine isn't working now. please help.

```
 // Show XY results
Mat3b xyres;
cvtColor(img, xyres, COLOR_GRAY2BGR);
for (int i = 0; i < rects.size(); ++i)
{
    rectangle(xyres, rects[i], Scalar(0, 0, 255), 2);
}

imshow("XY-Cut Result", xyres);
Size size2(400, 450);
    resize(xyres, xyres, size2);
waitKey(0);
```

The image isn't getting resized. could anyone tell me the problem?

Answer (score 2):

When I reproduce the code the image is resized as it is set to the size of (400,450).
But as you call `imshow` first you won't notice that in the shown image.

Rearrange your code like the follwing:

```
Mat3b xyres;
cvtColor(img, xyres, COLOR_GRAY2BGR);
for(int i = 0; i < rects.size(); ++i)
{
  rectangle(xyres, rects[i], Scalar(0,0,255), 2);
}
Size size2(400,450);
imshow("XY-Cut Result", xyres);
waitKey(0);
```